# RecyclerView max hight is exeeding the display

Tags: xml, android-layout

I want to set the max hight of my RecyclerView not to exeed my constraint layout max parameters. I tried many solutions from stack overflow but nothing seems to work.

Colors are just to make it more visible

What i have

[image]

Max hight should be this

[image]

What i have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NotfallSelbsthilfeSkillsHochStressEditActivity">

    <!--Actionbar Notfall Selbsthilfe Skills list Hoch-Stress bearbeiten-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_design_main"
        app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <!--Relativelayout of back arrow-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp">

            <!--ImageButton of back arrow-->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_backArrow"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--Relative View of actionbar headline-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

            <!--Textview of actionbar headline Notfall Selbsthilfe Skills list Hoch-Stress bearbeiten-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="@string/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_bearbeiten"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <!--ImageView of background-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:src="@color/red2"/>

    <!--Constraintlayout for content inside Hoch_Stress bearbeiten-->
    <!--RecyclerView for added Skills-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_skill_recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"

        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="710dp"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_actionbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_add"
        />

    <!--ImageView for button to add Skills-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_add"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:src="@drawable/add_black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_skill_recycleView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Whatever i try won't work and the recyclerView always exeeds the screen limit and won't let the user access the add button anymore.

My button more and more gets pushed of the screen

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can greatly simplify your layout. You don't need the nested _RelativeLayouts_ or the nested _ConstraintLayout_.  Remove all _match_parent_ sizes from the chilfren of your top-level _ConstraintLayout_ and use `0dp` with the appropriate constraints. Once simplified, make the _RecyclerView's_ height `0dp` and place in in a vertical [chain](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout#constrain-chain) with the other components.

Comment: Okey, thanks for your help. I tried to do what you suggested but also with the 0dp for the recyclerView it won't work. With 0dp the recyclerView does not even show the layout. I have updated the code above how it is now. The nested Layout thing i still don't 100% understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your layout. In general, I removed all *match_parent* sizes in direct children of the *ConstraintLayout* replacing them with `0dp` and the constraints to the sides of the *ConstraintLayout*. I also placed the *RecyclerView* and the bottom *ImageView* into a vertical chain assuming that you want the *ImageView* to be *below* the *RecyclerView*.

Here is the updated layout. I made several changes to color, drawables, etc. The core layout is still the same.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NotfallSelbsthilfeSkillsHochStressEditActivity">

    <!--Actionbar Notfall Selbsthilfe Skills list Hoch-Stress bearbeiten-->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp">

            <!--ImageButton of back arrow-->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_backArrow"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--Relative View of actionbar headline-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp">

            <!--Textview of actionbar headline Notfall Selbsthilfe Skills list Hoch-Stress bearbeiten-->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Some text here"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <!--ImageView of background-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:src="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--Constraintlayout for content inside Hoch_Stress bearbeiten-->
    <!--RecyclerView for added Skills-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_skill_recycleView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="710dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_actionbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <!--ImageView for button to add Skills-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_add"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notfall_selbsthilfe_skills_hochStress_list_bearbeiten_skill_recycleView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how the updated layout looks in the Android Studio designer:

[image]

I didn't do any structural changes to the toolbar, but you can remove the *RelativeLayouts* in the toolbar as well,

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now i understand what you mean by nested layouts. This line `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"` was the key. I changed it to `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` and with `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"` i pushed the button and the recyclerview up together as i want it to be.